# Move MySQL database while instance is online

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL instance containing a number of databases, one of which is an archive database (although using the INNODB rather than ARCHIVE storage engine) that is not queried or written to in normal operation.

The data filesystem is filling up and I'd like to move the archive database's data directory to a different filesystem (and then symlink it back, obviously). If there are no SQL statements attempting to query or update the data during the move, can I safely do this while the MySQL instance and the other databases stay online and in use?

I plan to rsync the database directory to the new filesystem, then rename the old one on the original filesystem to something different and create the new symlink. lsof reports that MySQL does have the .ibd files open, so presumably it would have to reopen them.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet for transferring would be to setup a trigger so that when something is created in the old database it is mimicked in the new.

You can then start and change where the database client is pointing without the worry of data is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, using MYISAM storage engine, but I think with INNODB it would be the same:

[mysql "hotcopy" and symlinking](https://serverfault.com/questions/569182/mysql-hotcopy-and-symlinking)