# mysql "hotcopy" and symlinking

Tags: mysql, partition

this is a question in planning migration.

mysql server 5.1.58-1-log (Debian) has datadir set to /dbs0 on disk0 and all myisam databases in it.

We would make new /dbs1 on disk1, stopping server, moving only some databases on /dbs1, for others staying in /dbs0 we would just create symlinks in /dbs1. After that done, re-setting datadir to /dbs1 and starting server.

This part is straightforward and it will work, expected to distribute IO and with that boost performance.

Suppose you are root. If new myisam database is created in datadir /dbs1, can it be moved to /dbs0 and then creating symlink in datadir, all this while the server is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving database named *dab* from **/dbs1** to **/dbs0** this easy way works and there is no need to stop server, not even flush lock it, just lock current database you are working on.

- start thread0:

  - connect to mysql, use *dab*
  - lock tables ...(all tables) write
  - start thread1

    - sudo mv /dbs1/dab /dbs0/dab && ln -s /dbs0/dab /dbs1/dab
  - end thread1
  - unlock tables, disconnect